# ¿Por que map me desordena su contenido?

Tags: java, map

Estoy recorriendo una matriz de objetos. Recorro la matriz y obtengo el objeto de esa posición de la matriz y la guardo en un tipo Map. Pero no sé porqué me descoloca todo el contenido.

```
public Map<String, String> obtenerCeldaHora(Hora[][] matriz){
        Map<String, String> horass = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(int i=0; i<matriz.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<matriz[0].length; j++) {
                Hora hora = matriz[i][j];
                horass.put("("+String.valueOf(i)+","+String.valueOf(j)+")", hora.toString());
            }
        }
        imprimir(horass);
        return horass;
    }

public void imprimir( Map<String, String> h) {
        Iterator it = h.keySet().iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()){
          String key = (String) it.next();
          System.out.println("Clave: " + key + " -> Valor: " + h.get(key));
        }
    }
```

Me sale esto en la consola:

> Clave: (1,2) -> Valor: { [true, false, false, true]}
> Clave: (2,0) -> Valor: { [false, true, false, false]}
> Clave: (0,2) -> Valor: { [false, false, true, true]}
> Clave: (1,1) -> Valor: { [false, true, true, false]}
> Clave: (2,1) -> Valor: { [true, true, false, true]}
> Clave: (2,2) -> Valor: { [false, false, false, true]}
> Clave: (0,1) -> Valor: { [false, true, false, true]}
> Clave: (1,0) -> Valor: { [true, false, false, false]}
> Clave: (0,0) -> Valor: { [false, true, true, false]}

***Se supone que cuando ejecuto para imprimir el mapa debería salir esto***

> (0,0) -> Valor: { [false, true, true, false]}
> (0,1) -> Valor: { [false, true, false, true]}
> (2,0) -> Valor: { [false, true, false, false]}
> ...
> Debería salir en orden, ¿sabríais decirme porque me lo desordena?

Comment: Lo he arreglado, he usado el linkedMap de java, que si mantiene el orden de insercción. Gracias de todas formas @Lobos

Comment: Un HashMap no garantiza conservar el orden en el que se ingresan los elementos (o algún otro orden arbitrario). Si es importante, debes usar otra estructura de datos

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes solucionar usando LinkedHashMap en lugar de HashMap.

```
LinkedHashMap<String,String> s = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    
        s.put("uno","dos");
        s.put("tres","cuatro");
    
        for(Map.Entry<String,String> ss : s.entrySet()){
            System.out.println(ss);
        }
```

Comment: Gracias, pero ya me di cuenta. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando un [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)

> [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)  **Esta clase no garantiza el orden del mapa**; en
> particular, no garantiza que el pedido se mantenga constante en el
> tiempo.

Deberías usar un [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

> [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)  Esta implementación se diferencia de HashMap en
> que mantiene una lista doblemente vinculada que se ejecuta en todas
> sus entradas. **Esta lista enlazada define el orden de iteración, que
> normalmente es el orden en el que se insertaron las claves en el mapa
> (orden de inserción).**

```
public Map<String, String> obtenerCeldaHora(Hora[][] matriz){
        Map<String, String> horass = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        for(int i=0; i<matriz.length; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<matriz[0].length; j++) {
                Hora hora = matriz[i][j];
                horass.put("("+String.valueOf(i)+","+String.valueOf(j)+")", hora.toString());
            }
        }
        imprimir(horass);
        return horass;
    }
```